# How to ignore Foreign Key Constraints in Entity Framework Core SQLite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

Foreign Key constraint failed use SQLite with Entity Framework Core

I have relations in table

```
[Table("organizations")]
public class Organizations
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("parent_id")]
    [ForeignKey("id")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [Column("person_id")]
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
 }


public DbSet<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }

using (var db = new SQLiteDbContext($"Filename={dbPath};"))
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;");
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PRAGMA ignore_check_constraints=true;");
    db.Organizations.AddRange(organizationsResult.Rows);
}
```

I get an error from the Sqlite database:

> {"SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'"}

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The PRAGMA looses effect if the connection is closed. You need to increase the lifetime of the connection by calling `db.Database.OpenConnection()` and `CloseConnection()` before and after.

You can also call `optionsBiulder.UseSqlite(connectionString, x => x.SuppressForeignKeyEnforcement())` to prefent EF from automatically turning foreign key enforcement on per connection.

**Entity Framework Core 3 Update:**

For EF Core 3.0 SuppressForeignKeyEnforcement has been removed. see learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/…

Use `"Foreign Keys = False"` in the connection string instead. Eg.

```
connectionString = "Data Source=Data.db;Password=yourpassword;Foreign Keys=False"
```

Comment: Ditto. Thanks Bricelam.

Comment: For EF Core 3.0 SuppressForeignKeyEnforcement has been removed. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#pragma

Use "Foreign Keys = False"  in the connection string instead. Eg. connectionString =  "Data Source=Data.db;Password=yourpassword;Foreign Keys=False"

Comment: Foreign Keys = False, this doesn't seem to be working on .NET 6 for SQL server. Any other possible ways to ignore Foreign Key? @BrettManners

Comment: @Sudhu You're looking for issue [#15854](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15854)